# Bootstrap 2 Modal partially blocked by soft keyboard

Tags: javascript, android, jquery, css, twitter-bootstrap

I've been using Bootstrap 2 modal window to display some forms, recently I tried to make my website responsive. After some tweaking, I finally made the modal windows look good on the phones, but I got one final problem left:

part of the modal window would be blocked by the soft keyboard and for some reason the viewport refuses to shift upwards. And because it is a Bootstrap 2 modal window, it refuses to scroll, then the lower part of the form is just block

please help! thanks

Answer (score 0):

Unfortunately the design of the modal dialogs in 2.3 doesn't work well with long forms on mobile browsers ([bootstrap 2's own demo](http://getbootstrap.com/2.3.2/javascript.html#modals)). The good news is Bootstrap 3 has addressed this ([updated demo](http://getbootstrap.com/javascript/#modals)) but unfortunately you can't mix and match these components. The upside of doing the hard work of upgrading is you will get a solid mobile site that should work on modern phones for at least the near future.